# RegEx to get 2nd and 3rd variables between pipes

Tags: .net, regex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntndK.png)**Sample text:**

> Engineering | AB7407 | 007412665 | Jackie Browne | Drawing for
>   Construction

I need 2 RegEx. One can give me 2nd value after the first pipe AB7407
and second Redex can give me 3rd value after the 2nd pipe 007412665

**I tried following but it gives me the sample text back:**

```
^(?<field1>[^|]+),(?<field2>[^|]+),(?<field3>[^|]+),(?<field4>[^|]+),(?<field5>[^|]+)$
```

**Result:**

> Engineering | AB7407 | 007412665 | Jackie Browne | Drawing for
>   Construction

Can anyone please suggest what is going on with my Regex.

Comment: Or you could use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html), or split the string by pipes and get the second and fourth values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim x = "Engineering | AB7407 | 007412665 | Jackie Browne | Drawing for Construction"
Dim parts = x.Split(" | ")
```

`parts(1)` now contains the second chunk of string, `parts(2)` contains the 3rd. This is VB, but the approach for c# or whatever you're using is similar.

To fix your regex:

```
^(?<field1>[^|]+) \| (?<field2>[^|]+) \| (?<field3>[^|]+) \| (?<field4>[^|]+) \| (?<field5>[^|]+)$
```

If you must have 2 regexes,

```
(?<=^[^|]+ \| )[^|]+
```

matches the second chunk, and

```
(?<=^(?:[^|]+ \| ){2})[^|]+
```

matches the 3rd.

Comment: Good code but I can't have code like this in SharePoint Workflow.

Comment: @qarminjamil I have updated my answer to correct your regex. You can test this [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am almost there. I need to figure out a way (In SharePoint 2010, Workflow, how to get field 2 and field 3).

Comment: @qarminjamil I have never used workflow, so I am not sure, but if you could post the code you are using to match against the regex I'm sure I could figure it out.

Comment: @qarminjamil I have updated the answer to give you 2 separate regexes. You need not use capturing groups with these.

Comment: for some reason the above regex not working. It doesn't split the value by pipe when i run the workflow.

Comment: I meant the long regex does not work with Nintex. However, the 2 short ones works. Like this one (?<=^[^|]+ \| )[^|]+ to get the 2nd value from the string.

Comment: A regex doesn't split a string. All it does is return capturing groups that you can refer to later, separately, however I do not know how you can do this in sharepoint. Just use the other two regexen I provided.

Comment: In nintex Regex with split can be stored in a collection variable. I added a picture in the original post for your reference. But it seems that it is spliting into an array in design time. But it does not put it in array in run time. I may end up using the 2 shorter regexs. I have to add 2 more actions in my workflow as oppose to Store in a collection, then use collection operation which store index value in index variable and result in result variable. i was then going to use loop action to get the index =1 and index =2 values. oh well.

Comment: @qarminjamil I don't know if this facilitates looping, but if you change the number in the second short regex to 1, it returns the second chunk. If you change it to 3, it returns the 4th chunk.

Comment: How can fix this (?<=^(?:[^|]+ \| ){2})[^|]+ so that i can remove all the spaces from the 2nd value. (I got the other piece working)

Comment: I dont trim option (I do but it's too late because spaces are being feed in the collection and i can't remove spaces from collection value)

Answer (score 4):

I would do this:

```
 string original = "Engineering | AB7407 | 007412665 | Jackie Browne | Drawing for Construction";
 string[] split = original.Split('|');
 string firstcode = split[1];
 string secondcode = split[2];
```

If you want to remove all leading/trailing whitespaces:

```
string secondcode = split[2].Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is the wrong way to process this. `cut -f 2,3 -d '|'` on the command line will provide what you're looking for.

Any programming language should have a string split function that will turn your string into an array of strings based on your pipe delimiter. Use that instead of a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use groups

```
^(?<field1>.*?)\|(?<field2>.*?)\|(?<field3>.*?)\|(?<field4>.*?)\|(?<field5>.*?)$
```

groups named `field2` and `field3` contains your data